# I2C not working unless its through a mosfet (not level shifting)

Tags: arduino, mosfet, i2c, esp8266, level-shifting

Ive been dipping my toes into the world of hardware over the last year and I'm working on a project that i've been stumped on for a few months now. I've made progress on alot of roadblocks but this one has me stumped.

I learned about the DDC protocol that computer monitors use to allow software to control certain aspects of a monitors setting (Input, brightness, color settings etc). Its just I2C. Heres the wiki page for it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel

Essentially pin number 15, 16 on an HDMI port serve as SCL and SDL respectively.

using the linux package ddccontrol, i was able to change the monitor source input from HDMI to DP. This answer provides some context: https://askubuntu.com/questions/860761/ubuntu-command-line-to-change-input-source-on-a-display-monitor

Running the package in debug mode I was able to extract the payload being sent across i2C. Using a logic analyzer I was able to confirm the payload as well get the address it was writing too.

So I wrote an arduino sketch to see If I could replicate this. I put it on an arduino uno and BOOM, it worked!

Now I wanted to port this over to an ESP8266 micro controller. Minor changes to the arduino sketch and it was ported over. However there was a whole heap of weird behavior. The logic analyzer showed things looping and no ACKs from the slave. After some research I realized theres two main differences between the esp and the arduino

1) esp achieves i2c through bit banging instead of dedicated hardware

2) esp is 3.3v device and Arduino is 5v

I realized the HDMI protocol defines the voltage at 5v so I bought a logic level converted to test with([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07YZTW2SM/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07YZTW2SM))

I plugged it all in, adding pull up resistors to both sides of the converted signal. and...

IT WORKED....

However i had made a mistake. I forgot to connect the 5v power source into the HV side of the logic lever converted. So it wasnt even converting the signal... **why did this work???**

I confirmed that without the 5v side connected, the logic level converter wasnt converting anything at all. 3.3v on both sides. I plugged in the 5v side and to my surprise, no ACK from the monitor....

Im pretty stumped here. I thought for sure the monitor just required 5v logic levels...

What im assuming is maybe the mosfets are cleaning up the signal somehow? Anyone have any idea on what happened here? I'm happy I have a working prototype but I'd like to know what exactly its doing.

Comment: @jsotola Done deal!

Heres a very rough schematic of what ive got: https://imgur.com/fh5NrXF

Again this schematic does NOT work... however disconnecting the 5V line to the logic level converter allows it all to work (also removing the pull up resistors after the 5v line is disconnected).

Heres what the lines look like with the WORKING circuit (without the 5V connected): https://imgur.com/a/p6aRBfp

I also notice that the ACK seem to happen at a faster rate? Maybe the speeds are mismatched between the monitor and

Comment: What kind of levelshifter are you using? Is it possible that it does the pull down if not powered correctly? What happens if you disconnect the slave in the "working" configuration i.e. 5V not attached?

Comment: It's a bi-directional level shifter. Since the HV side is not powered it's still 3.3v on the other side. Which means the 5v slave is still able to pull it down. In this case the whole circuit should just work without any shifter. Without the slave there's just no ACK

Comment: I hoped for more information about the levelshifters. Sadly searching the product page does not really yield anything useful like a schematics or similar. I would suspect that the ACKs are actually no real responses from the slave but an artifact by the wrongly powered mosfets/circuit. Reason why I belief so is the missing ACK if correctly powered. My gut feeling why it works with the arduino and not the ESP is that maybe something like clock stretching is needed but does not work properly.